# Matrix Factorization, loss function derivation

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

I want to compute the partial derivative of my loss function for $W$
\begin{align}
L(W) &= \frac{1}{2}\| X-WZ^{T}\|^{2}_{forb} + \frac{1}{2} \lambda_{w}\| W \| \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(X - WZ^{T})^{T}(X-WZ^{T}) + \lambda_{w}W^{T}W  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\big(X^{T}X - X^{T}WZ^{T} - (WZ^{T})^{T}X + (WZ^{T})WZ^{T} \big) + \lambda_{w}W^{T}W
\end{align}

But I must be doing something wrong, as when I derive the last equality with respect to $W$, the dimensions doesn't work any more. $X$ is a $d \times n$ matrix, $W$ $d \times k$ and $Z^{T}$ is $k \times n$

\begin{align}
\frac{dL(W)}{\delta w} &= \frac{1}{2}\big(\!-\! X^{T}Z^{T} - (Z^{T})^{T}X + (Z^{T})WZ^{T}  + ZWZ^{T}\big) + \frac{2}{2} \lambda_{w}W^{T}
\end{align}

The dimension problem can be seen with $X^{T}Z^{T}$ which is $n\times d \times k\times n$. I believe I am missing some derivation rules, and I would be glad if some one would point them out, as I don't find the issue.

Best.

Comment: I am not sure you expand the norm correctly. Let's take the first term (the squared norm of the residuals). Your second line is what you obtain when using the 2-norm and X is a column. In your case, the Frobenius norm squared in the first line is a scalar, while the matrix product in the second line gives a NxN matrix. You may have to take the trace of that matrix (and do the same with $W^T W$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $forb$ is the Frobenius norm, and that the penalty term is also a squared Frobenius norm, $\lVert W \rVert_{\mathrm{F}}^2$, then your first step is incorrect.

The Frobenius norm squared in the first line is a scalar, while the matrix product in the second line gives an $N$x$N$ matrix. You need to take the trace of that matrix to obtain the Frobenius norm squared:

\begin{align}
L(W) &= \frac{1}{2} \lVert X-WZ^{T}\rVert_{\mathrm{F}}^2 + \frac{1}{2} \lambda_{w}\lVert W \rVert_{\mathrm{F}}^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{tr}\left[(X - WZ^{T})^{T}(X-WZ^{T})\right] + \lambda_{w}\, \mathrm{tr}\left[ W^{T}W \right]
.
\end{align}

Once the product is expanded, you can use the fact that the trace of the sum is the sum of the traces as well as some useful properties from ["Matrix Calculus - Notes on the Derivative of a Trace" by
Johannes Traa](http://cal.cs.illinois.edu/~johannes/research/matrix%20calculus.pdf) to compute the desired derivative.

Comment: Ok! So the mistake was from the start, thank you!

Comment: I've added a reference to a tutorial on the derivative of the trace